# Hex array to int

Tags: c

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char buff[3];

    buff[0] = 0x00;
    buff[1] = 0x11;
    buff[2] = 0x00;
    buff[3] = 0x00;

    int var = (buff[0]<<24)|buff[1]|buff[2]|buff[3];
    printf ("%u\n", var);

    return 0;
}
```

And the result shown below,

```
$./a.out
17
```

Comment: Surely you meant to write `(buff[0]<<24)|(buff[1]<<16)|(buff[2]<<8)|buff[3]`?

Comment: buff[3] is too far for an array declared with size 3

Comment: The output is somewhat unexpected, but you should provide a program that doesn't write off end of buffer and try it again.

Comment: You are accessing the array out-of-bounds and thereby invoking undefined behavior. Thus the compiler behaves correctly, by giving you a completely random result in return.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. `char[3]` is an array of 3 chars, with legal indices 0, 1, and 2.

What you refer to as `buff[3]` must be something completely different, probably even re-initialized after the `buff[3] = 0x00` assignment. You could be getting a SIGSEGV or a GPF instead of 17.

Answer (score 2):

--- edited in response to 9000's observation ---

In addition to the shifting mentioned below, one should allocate an array large enough to cover all the indices one uses

```
unsigned char buff[4];
```

My results (entire program copied below) are 1116160, which corresponds to 0x00110000

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char buff[4];

    buff[0] = 0x00;
    buff[1] = 0x11;
    buff[2] = 0x00;
    buff[3] = 0x00;

    int var = (buff[0]<<24)|(buff[1]<<16)|(buff[2]<<8)|buff[3];
    printf ("%u\n", var);

    return 0;
}
```

Your results might differ slightly depending on they byte order of your machine.

--- original post follows ---

The last three bytes are overlaying each other.  Odds are you simply forgot to shift them into place.

Assuming that's a good assumption, your code should look more like

```
int var = (buff[0]<<24)|(buff[1]<<16)|(buff[2]<<8)|buff[3];
printf ("%u\n", var);

return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
int var = (buff[0]<<24)|(buff[1]<<16)|(buff[2]<<8)|buff[3];
```

if your buffer is [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) or

```
int var = buff[0]|(buff[1]<<8)|(buff[2]<<16)|(buff[3]<<24);
```

if your buffer is [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Also, your array is too little - the number you specify in the brackets when you declare an array is the *size* of the array, not the maximum index. It has to be `unsigned char buff[4];`.

Answer (score 0):

`(buff[0]<<24)` is evaluted to `0`

`buff[1]` is evaluated to `0x11` (`17` decimal)

`buff[2]` is evaluated to `0`

`buff[3]` is evaluated to `0`

```
0 | 17 | 0 | 0 == 17
```

Comment: value is not 17, since 0x00110000 = 1114112

Comment: Nope, the value OP is computing is not 0x00110000 but 0x00 | 0x11 | 0x00 | 0x00. Please read OP question again. This answer is explaining why he is getting 17.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't given an indication of what the result should be, I'll go out on a limb and guess that this is the problem:

```
int var = (buff[0]<<24)|buff[1]|buff[2]|buff[3];
```

should be

```
int var = (buff[0]<<24)|(buff[0]<<16)|(buff[0]<<8)|buff[3];
```